# How to scroll div when overlapped

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a problem with scroll 
I have a DIV populated automatically with elements in position fixed

the lower div contain the scroll function at z-index 90, the upper div at z-index 100 contains element on hover

by scrolling the lowe div the scroll get stopped once I'm hover the other one...

I have a simplified way to show the issue. I would like to keep the gren DIV scrolling even if i'm over the red one on top...

```
overflow:scroll;
```

[sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/0yxnaywu/23/)

Answer (score 0):

Simply declare `pointer-events: none;` on your red div.
This will fix the issue of capturing mouse events, but on the other hand it prevents you from interacting with the element altogether.

```css
.parent {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color:green;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow:scroll;
    z-index: 100;
    display: block; 
    cursor: pointer;
}

.child1 {

    /* this prevents mouse events being captured by this element*/
    pointer-events:none;
    
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 110;
    background-color: red;
    top:50px;
    height:40px;
    width:120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis 
</div>
<div class="child1">
hello world filler
</div>
```

Comment: the problem is that on that div i have also some on click events, so i need to be able to catch the mouse event...

Comment: In that case - not possible. How would you want to tell which element the mouse interaction is supposed to target?

Comment: well, i want to pass click on the child but keep scroll on main one... there's a way to segregate them?